# iOS working in simulator, on iphone via xcode but crashes when copying the archive via itunes

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, archive

I am quite new to iOS development but i managed to realise a webview with additional app-functions. It works fine, when i run it in the simulator or on my iphone. But archiving it, moving it to itunes and dragging it on the iphone, works, but, when starting it after the permission request for the locator, it crashes.

I managed to fin the crash report. Looks strange. I really need a hint, what might have happened.

This is the crash report:

```
Incident Identifier: F7215F67-393B-4E9A-8875-547B9198EE12
CrashReporter Key:   423bff97deb4a1f174be1a741546d33ba41e818d
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:         WE Ticket [4350]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/F3724443-4B28-418F-BA4C-155DB2EF34E7/WE Ticket.app/WE Ticket
Identifier:      WE Ticket
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-07-11 16:31:10.119 +0200
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.4 (10B350)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3217d3e2 __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39e7895e objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3217d302 +[NSException raise:format:] + 102
3   UIKit                           0x341290cc -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1632
4   UIKit                           0x341286fa -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 230
5   UIKit                           0x34021074 -[UIViewController loadView] + 88
6   UIKit                           0x33fab44c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 64
7   UIKit                           0x340001f2 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 22
8   UIKit                           0x34000138 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 24
9   UIKit                           0x3400001c -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 28
10  UIKit                           0x33ffff48 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 268
11  UIKit                           0x33fff694 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 60
12  UIKit                           0x33fff57c -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 320
13  UIKit                           0x33fd055c -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 176
14  UIKit                           0x33f8f8c2 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 254
15  QuartzCore                      0x33d3b50e -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 210
16  QuartzCore                      0x33d3b0b0 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 456
17  QuartzCore                      0x33d69eca -[CALayer layoutIfNeeded] + 138
18  UIKit                           0x340390dc -[UIViewController window:setupWithInterfaceOrientation:] + 204
19  UIKit                           0x340382c6 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 3598
20  UIKit                           0x340374aa -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 42
21  UIKit                           0x34037434 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 64
22  UIKit                           0x3416ccb4 __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke_0 + 100
23  UIKit                           0x33ff567e -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 214
24  UIKit                           0x33ff53c2 -[UIWindow setAutorotates:forceUpdateInterfaceOrientation:] + 690
25  UIKit                           0x33ff4d2a -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 150
26  UIKit                           0x33febe86 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 366
27  UIKit                           0x33fe7af0 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 360
28  UIKit                           0x340291dc -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 56
29  WE Ticket                       0x00050cf8 0x4f000 + 7416
30  UIKit                           0x33feca9c -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 248
31  UIKit                           0x33fec620 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1164
32  UIKit                           0x33fe482e -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 694
33  UIKit                           0x33f8cd1a -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1006
34  UIKit                           0x33f8c7a8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
35  UIKit                           0x33f8c1ea _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6194
36  GraphicsServices                0x35ca45f2 _PurpleEventCallback + 586
37  GraphicsServices                0x35ca4222 PurpleEventCallback + 30
38  CoreFoundation                  0x321523e2 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 30
39  CoreFoundation                  0x32152386 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
40  CoreFoundation                  0x3215120a __CFRunLoopRun + 1378
41  CoreFoundation                  0x320c4238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
42  CoreFoundation                  0x320c40c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
43  UIKit                           0x33fe3468 -[UIApplication _run] + 664
44  UIKit                           0x33fe02b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
45  WE Ticket                       0x00050a32 0x4f000 + 6706
46  libdyld.dylib                   0x3a2a5b1c start + 0


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a36c350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2e2fb2 pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a31f366 abort + 90
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x398c7dda abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x398c5094 default_terminate() + 20
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39e78a58 _objc_terminate() + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x398c5118 safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x398c51b0 std::terminate() + 16
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x398c6626 __cxa_rethrow + 90
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39e789b0 objc_exception_rethrow + 8
10  CoreFoundation                  0x320c429c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
11  CoreFoundation                  0x320c40c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
12  UIKit                           0x33fe3468 -[UIApplication _run] + 664
13  UIKit                           0x33fe02b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
14  WE Ticket                       0x00050a32 0x4f000 + 6706
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x3a2a5b1c start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a36cd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2baad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2ba7f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2ba680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a35c5d0 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a297d22 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 806
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a293374 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 32

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a36cd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2baad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2ba7f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2ba680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a35be30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a35bfd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x321522b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3215102c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x320c4238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x320c40c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x380cc390 RunWebThread(void*) + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2c50de _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2c4fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a36cd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2baad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2ba7f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2ba680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a35be30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a35bfd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x321522b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3215102c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x320c4238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x320c40c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   Foundation                      0x32a11888 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 304
7   Foundation                      0x32a9522c __NSThread__main__ + 968
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2c50de _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2c4fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a36cd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2baad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2ba7f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2ba680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a36c594 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x32156474 __CFSocketManager + 676
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2c50de _pthread_start + 306
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2c4fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x3be2e524
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3be2eb78      r6: 0x1d055384      r7: 0x2fdb1a14
    r8: 0x1d055360    r9: 0x00000300     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdb1a08      lr: 0x3a2e2fb7      pc: 0x3a36c350
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
   0x4f000 -    0x6dfff +WE Ticket armv7s  <335d70c9f2bf3c87b379793dc66138bb> /var/mobile/Applications/F3724443-4B28-418F-BA4C-155DB2EF34E7/WE Ticket.app/WE Ticket
0x2fe38000 - 0x2fe58fff  dyld armv7s  <67efe80b9d863d6bb30fe51e6e17b070> /usr/lib/dyld
0x31379000 - 0x31379fff  Accelerate armv7s  <f4e8c4c464953429ab6bd3160aadd176> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x3137a000 - 0x314b7fff  vImage armv7s  <49d3cf19d0a23f4d836fc313e5fd6bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x314b8000 - 0x315a4fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7s  <584e045442be39fc847ffe1a5e4c99b2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x315a5000 - 0x3185bfff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7s  <30a3e7dd8c603a9d81b5e42704ba5971> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x3185c000 - 0x318b4fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7s  <936354553eb93d2dafa76ffcad65f9b7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x318b5000 - 0x318c7fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7s  <5fae8715a0403315bb1991b79677f916> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x318c8000 - 0x318c8fff  vecLib armv7s  <30275ee8819331229ba21256d7b94596> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x31dd2000 - 0x31e97fff  CFNetwork armv7s  <ef41814d8641319c96cdeb1264d2d150> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x31e98000 - 0x31eeefff  CoreAudio armv7s  <19aa715b19a93a5c8563dbc706e899be> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x31f02000 - 0x320bafff  CoreData armv7s  <dee36bfc0c213492983c73d7bd83a27d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x320bb000 - 0x321edfff  CoreFoundation armv7s  <bd8e6c9f94b43e3d9af96a0f03ff3011> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x321ee000 - 0x32327fff  CoreGraphics armv7s  <ef057fe1c715314cabf133ec26fa718c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x32329000 - 0x32364fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7s  <163d7f8309a6350399bbb1fef6cde32c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x32548000 - 0x32563fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7s  <387d00a9ed55303b8936459a99869e07> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x32564000 - 0x32619fff  CoreImage armv7s  <7d7cd7998a113ed9b483e7dc9f388b05> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x3261a000 - 0x32672fff  CoreLocation armv7s  <24dab19c71e831d187b56fe095483c16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x326a7000 - 0x3270cfff  CoreMedia armv7s  <526b25ed6f4e31b790553bd80d46fec7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x32796000 - 0x327ecfff  CoreTelephony armv7s  <930c89780b123ecea46cff85c4989982> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x327ed000 - 0x3284ffff  CoreText armv7s  <a01bc990cb483e828f7c3e08cd446daf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x32850000 - 0x3285ffff  CoreVideo armv7s  <851591a704dc344aa2fc397094b4c622> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x329e4000 - 0x32ba7fff  Foundation armv7s  <0f73c35ada563c0bb2ce402d282faefd> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x32d62000 - 0x32dabfff  IOKit armv7s  <4e5e55f27bbb35bab7af348997bfac17> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x32dac000 - 0x32f84fff  ImageIO armv7s  <e04300f6e6b232ce8a02139d8f18dfdc> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x3349b000 - 0x334f4fff  MobileCoreServices armv7s  <b0d1162a8ab03529bb90e416895b568a> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x335e4000 - 0x335ebfff  OpenGLES armv7s  <c9c8f7cbfbe5397382286b878bdf143c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x335ed000 - 0x335edfff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7s  <b7d1ddfeb0db36d6af7293fa625b12be> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x335f1000 - 0x335f3fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7s  <8bcac434962435a895fa0b0a3a33b7a1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x335f4000 - 0x335f8fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7s  <272a9de67f6632c3aebbe2407cfe716b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x335f9000 - 0x33638fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7s  <3a444257935236fab123e46e617c7a8d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x33d38000 - 0x33e4cfff  QuartzCore armv7s  <b28fd354be3c38a2965e6368fa35e0c7> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x33e9a000 - 0x33ec8fff  Security armv7s  <e1fcc8913eba360c868f51558a01cf24> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x33f47000 - 0x33f86fff  SystemConfiguration armv7s  <0fb8d4a2fa8f30ce837e068a046e466b> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x33f89000 - 0x344dcfff  UIKit armv7s  <62bee9294ca13738bd7ff14365dc8561> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x344dd000 - 0x3451cfff  VideoToolbox armv7s  <57487f6e3c38304ab0aa14dd16043f5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x3480a000 - 0x3480dfff  AggregateDictionary armv7s  <52b69c81243d3e7ea280defa4802aa0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x34c39000 - 0x34c74fff  AppSupport armv7s  <7d6122cb42363dc981247c926e637a34> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x34ce7000 - 0x34cf0fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7s  <ec78d21573a23c34b6cec05ba56928f1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x34d20000 - 0x34d37fff  BackBoardServices armv7s  <7fd28bde9e3b3a62a5758e9e859db9fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x34d41000 - 0x34d65fff  Bom armv7s  <f35bf1c1b24a3742847383801ac37505> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x34f9b000 - 0x34fa0fff  CommonUtilities armv7s  <eb0b7e85b57e32f38dc498c0ee97aa7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x35266000 - 0x35267fff  CoreSurface armv7s  <55826212d8b4352b87d80f93bc9b25c6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x352d4000 - 0x352d9fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7s  <3b190badb14f3771b353fcd829719c80> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x35500000 - 0x35519fff  DictionaryServices armv7s  <27298e235f2c35938e1033517b1196a7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x3558c000 - 0x3599ffff  FaceCoreLight armv7s  <432cbaeb84743441b9286532bc36c96d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x35b97000 - 0x35ba3fff  GenerationalStorage armv7s  <4e1afa8de682332ba6a042a6000c636e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x35ba4000 - 0x35c9dfff  GeoServices armv7s  <12d1626ed0f733d7bacca40380622f99> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x35c9e000 - 0x35ca9fff  GraphicsServices armv7s  <44b33c403523309c9e930818c7fced34> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x35f95000 - 0x35fe1fff  IMFoundation armv7s  <55151f53b10934c3a5faac54e354f3f1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x35fe8000 - 0x35fe9fff  IOAccelerator armv7s  <832913083f7f347fba1340263ff13b52> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x35fea000 - 0x35feffff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7s  <828a36a2325738bb8f2d4b97730d253a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x35ff0000 - 0x35ff4fff  IOSurface armv7s  <9925fbc4a08d3a17b72ac807cbbba8ba> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x3603e000 - 0x361e5fff  JavaScriptCore armv7s  <f7be721eee903a93a7de361e5627445e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x364e0000 - 0x3650dfff  MobileAsset armv7s  <e3217ead58d5390395de360b3ca3a10a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x36552000 - 0x36555fff  MobileInstallation armv7s  <7cbe167946123bbea56ae58208e09762> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x36556000 - 0x3655cfff  MobileKeyBag armv7s  <5c7d50e11eb537ae89ea12cb7ddd3935> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x365b9000 - 0x365bcfff  MobileSystemServices armv7s  <5796fff2895f38e4b0f844269d4fbae5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x36e94000 - 0x36eb8fff  OpenCL armv7s  <9fb5ca4c594c3ae8baf7e0b0c299733b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x374cd000 - 0x374f5fff  PrintKit armv7s  <7109f645a9ca3a4997b4172aed228723> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x374f6000 - 0x3756afff  ProofReader armv7s  <e391e8d141c5352d978e5fde23afaaad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x3756b000 - 0x37573fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7s  <edc3f72bf38c3d81954ac85f489a17e8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x376af000 - 0x376c0fff  SpringBoardServices armv7s  <bb92c069669b36959d3e82d4144f4264> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x3784b000 - 0x3784dfff  TCC armv7s  <95c2aa492cc03862bd7bbfae6fa62b1b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x3786c000 - 0x37879fff  TelephonyUtilities armv7s  <aa759d908b903f978ab6803b7947e524> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TelephonyUtilities
0x37cfe000 - 0x37d9efff  UIFoundation armv7s  <e3a40cee28653c4485a4918016ff2b8e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x380a2000 - 0x380c1fff  WebBookmarks armv7s  <ab55332c13da33fd825ea6204338fe19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x380c2000 - 0x389f2fff  WebCore armv7s  <b87e1ce4e58231108043c9ae79bb01d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x389f3000 - 0x38acffff  WebKit armv7s  <6bd57205f7a43f6eb49f3037b57cc5f6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x38b7a000 - 0x38b81fff  XPCObjects armv7s  <e6846a96a21d382f9fffd6a4536c0aa7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
0x396ec000 - 0x396f2fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7s  <9111bc894a4f3ef683f5ef4d699a861b> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x396f3000 - 0x39709fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7s  <770ebb2f7d9a35749e6da5d1980c244f> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x39721000 - 0x3972dfff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7s  <7cf3ae0983a830d1a5dc91edb216b3f8> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x3973f000 - 0x3973ffff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7s  <12daef214fd234158028c97c22dc5cca> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x39861000 - 0x3986dfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7s  <0f4a8d65b05a364abca1a97e2ae72cb5> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x3986e000 - 0x39877fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7s  <f54b70863d9c3751bb59253b1cb4c706> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x39878000 - 0x398c3fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7s  <3beff5a5233b3f51ab2fc748b68e9519> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x398c4000 - 0x398d7fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7s  <f47a5c7bc24c3e4fa73f11b61af635da> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x39908000 - 0x399f5fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7s  <81d6972465103fa3b85b4125f0ad33f1> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x399f6000 - 0x39b3ffff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7s  <642482cfc34a3a3b97bd731258dcdc6a> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x39b47000 - 0x39b47fff  liblangid.dylib armv7s  <ffb53baa33ba3642a55737311f17a672> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x39b4a000 - 0x39b51fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7s  <d484b93ed83c3b0bb5c6721134662453> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x39e70000 - 0x39f6efff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7s  <1d499765d38c3c8fa92b363f529a02dd> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x3a032000 - 0x3a047fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7s  <3f7be9d397d63b8e931d21bd5f49b0eb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x3a06c000 - 0x3a0f2fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7s  <758898189dca32a5a19e5200b8952110> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3a0f3000 - 0x3a13ffff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7s  <249e8ca1717b370287bb556bbd96e303> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x3a140000 - 0x3a166fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7s  <96b463f0ffa0344699fce4d48aa623bc> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x3a16a000 - 0x3a217fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7s  <e87724e212573773a60bc56815cec706> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x3a218000 - 0x3a238fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7s  <c52fbe01ce7b35c799630e97e8f1318b> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x3a239000 - 0x3a245fff  libz.1.dylib armv7s  <b64a5c1989ba3ba4aafae83d841f9496> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x3a246000 - 0x3a249fff  libcache.dylib armv7s  <911ce99a94623ef1ae1ea786055fd558> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x3a24a000 - 0x3a250fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7s  <33140a5fa3fb3e5e8c6bb19bc0e21c5c> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x3a251000 - 0x3a253fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7s  <cd17f0ee3dbc38f99910d12a6056bf5a> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x3a254000 - 0x3a259fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7s  <5e733170766430eeaa4e7784e3c7555c> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x3a25a000 - 0x3a290fff  libcorecrypto.dylib armv7s  <a15c807dcb003ad69810546a578774d9> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x3a291000 - 0x3a2a1fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7s  <247a388103633e17b24be038eac612c0> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x3a2a2000 - 0x3a2a3fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7s  <f873dd712561350096b9452bf1fc4078> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x3a2a4000 - 0x3a2a5fff  libdyld.dylib armv7s  <d8d1e76c619b3a7cacfc4dc30a50d9bc> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x3a2a6000 - 0x3a2a6fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7s  <b0a1a911d4853feba44133e9ce499bc9> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x3a2a7000 - 0x3a2acfff  liblaunch.dylib armv7s  <69dd64aba1413e75967cd4ad0afa2c15> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x3a2ad000 - 0x3a2b0fff  libmacho.dylib armv7s  <5905b311c6fb376388e56a991bb3193d> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x3a2b1000 - 0x3a2b2fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7s  <b40e964d7c563296b38625bc7082d6a8> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x3a2b3000 - 0x3a2b3fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7s  <77a9976b82b73796a0bbc9783929a1e7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x3a2b4000 - 0x3a33afff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7s  <11bcf1060ec63c8b909a452e6f79be08> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x3a33b000 - 0x3a341fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7s  <94fab309ed9b35cdbc075cdda221bc70> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x3a342000 - 0x3a35afff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7s  <195d8eeb7c3f31bd916c0b5611abc0e7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x3a35b000 - 0x3a371fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7s  <a6afa72d4ec335d79b63aa47114cc24a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x3a372000 - 0x3a38efff  libsystem_m.dylib armv7s  <faafc8292d4935c4a78233e1d0879e13> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x3a38f000 - 0x3a39dfff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7s  <137f48e279a83d7496659c8e3d3729d4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x3a39e000 - 0x3a3a5fff  libsystem_notify.dylib armv7s  <df14146497cb3fa0a002eedbed49da65> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x3a3a6000 - 0x3a3a7fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7s  <85e91e99abc03db88eddc665424090b4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x3a3a8000 - 0x3a3a8fff  libunwind.dylib armv7s  <3b7ec561dbec3a199f09ea08a64e76ee> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x3a3a9000 - 0x3a3befff  libxpc.dylib armv7s  <0562a59bdf8d3f7783e93f35d7e724a8> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rejected for crashing on launch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779865/rejected-for-crashing-on-launch)

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075298/app-works-on-simulator-but-not-on-iphone

Comment: Try a clean, then archive again. It is possible the nib file is missing from the build.

Comment: I did a clean, no problem reports, but after copying the .ipa it still crashes

Comment: Ok, now i did a:

1. Checked the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: 
in the appDelegate
2. Clean
3. Build for Archive

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now i did a:

1. I checked the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: in the appDelegate. Not sure, if it matters, but the the name of the initialized Controller did not match exactly the name it was given during the initializiation. So it set them equal.
2. Made a "Clean"
3. Made a "Build for Archive"
4. Archived it and gave it a different name than before
5. Copied it, and it worked

Which step solved the problem, i do not know... but, at the moment, i don't care about it ;-)

Thanks for your hints.